# Python Class calling one function to another

Tags: python, class, oop

I have just started OOPS and am completely new to it. I have a very basic question regarding the different ways I can call a function within another function in same class.

```
class StuffAnimal:
def __init__(self,name,color,weight,issitting):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.weight = weight
    self.issitting = issitting
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.situation = " "
    
    
def standup (self):
    if self.issitting == True :
        print("the stuff toy is sitting")
        return "sit"
    else :
        print ("the stuff toy is not sitting")
        return "notsit"
    
def move_teddy (self):
    self.situation = standup(self.issitting)
    if self.situation == 'sit' :
        print ("teddy is not in the situation to move please change issitting to True")
        
    elif self.situation == 'notsit' :      
        print ("teddy is in the situation to move please give cordinates")
        self.x = int(input("x cordinates : "))
        self.y = int(input("y cordinates : "))
        print("teddy moved to ",self.x,self.y)
```

but when i tried to call the function I got the following error.

```
teddy.move_teddy()
NameError: name 'standup' is not defined
```

This doesn't works. Can someone explain where did I go wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As the method definition tells the method `def standup(self)`

- is a instance method, (because of `self`)
- does not accept parameters (because there is only `self`)

So the good way to cal it is

```
self.situation = self.standup()
```

---

Regarding the name of your methods, I'd say `standup` should set `issitting` to False, and define a `sitdown` method. Then the code of `move_teddy` would be more logic

```py
class StuffAnimal:
    def __init__(self, name, color, weight, issitting):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight
        self.issitting = issitting
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def standup(self):
        self.issitting = False
        print("the stuff toy is now up")

    def sitdown(self):
        self.issitting = True
        print("the stuff toy is now sit")

    def move_teddy(self):
        if self.issitting:
            print("teddy is not in the situation to move please change issitting to True")
        else:
            print("teddy is in the situation to move please give cordinates")
            self.x = int(input("x cordinates : "))
            self.y = int(input("y cordinates : "))
            print("teddy moved to ", self.x, self.y)
```

```py
teddy = StuffAnimal("teddy", "black", 20, True)
teddy.move_teddy()
teddy.standup()
teddy.move_teddy()
```

```
teddy is not in the situation to move please change issitting to True
the stuff toy is now up
teddy is in the situation to move please give cordinates
x cordinates : 12
y cordinates : 34
teddy moved to  12 34
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I think the standup and sitdown  makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

self parameter doesn't require to be called, and when you call a function from a class in the same class, your self. prefix !

```
class StuffAnimal:
def __init__(self,name,color,weight,issitting):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.weight = weight
    self.issitting = issitting
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.situation = " "
    
    
def standup (self):
    if self.issitting == True :
        print("the stuff toy is sitting")
        return "sit"
    else :
        print ("the stuff toy is not sitting")
        return "notsit"
    
def move_teddy (self):
    self.situation = self.standup()
    if self.situation == 'sit' :
        print ("teddy is not in the situation to move please change issitting to True")
        
    elif self.situation == 'notsit' :      
        print ("teddy is in the situation to move please give cordinates")
        self.x = int(input("x cordinates : "))
        self.y = int(input("y cordinates : "))
        print("teddy moved to ",self.x,self.y)
```